# Grouping and sorting in Rails and showing most recent highlighted

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple attachment models. I need to sort them by the type of Attachments. We have 3 types A, B, and C. From there I have to highlight the most recent attachment of each type and then have the other not so recent attachments underneath it. When the attachments are set the type is from a drop down for types A, B, and C. I've tried using group by and sort by functions but I don't believe I was using them correctly.

My Current Code

```
- @attachment.each do |attachment|
      %attachment-container
        .main-attachment
          %ul.inline
            %li
              %h3= attachment.attachment_type
              %dl
                %dd
                  Uploaded By
                  %span= attachment.uploader_name
                %dd
                  &#8226;
                %dd
                  = attachment.created_at
                %dd
                  &#8226;
                %dd
                  %button.add View previous attachments
              %p 
                = attachment.description    
            %li
              %a.btn.primary{:href => "#{attachment.url}"} Download       
        .more-reports{:style => "display: none"}(Should show least recent attachments of this type)
          %dl
            %dd
              Uploaded By
              %span= attachment.uploader_name
            %dd
              &#8226;
            %dd
              = attachment.created_at
            %dd
              &#8226;
            %li
              %a.btn.primary{:href => "#{attachment.url}"} Download
```

What I think I need to do is something like...(removed CSS)

```
-@attachment.attachment_type.each do |attachment|
    -attachment.attachment_type
    -attachment.each do
        -attachment.uploader_name
        -attachment.created_at(somehow needs to be only most recent)
        Download button here
        Somehow needs to be other not recent files.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, name your variable `@attachments` instead of `@attachment`.

In your controller, you can group the attachments by type like this

```
@attachments_by_type = @attachments.group_by(&:attachment_type)
@sorted_attachments_by_type = @attachments_by_type.inject({}) {|h, (k, v)| h[k] = v.sort_by{|a| -a.created_at; h}}
```

Now you have a hash with key as the type and value as the sorted attachments array. You can use it in view like below

```
-@sorted_attachment_by_type.each do |type, attachments|
    -type
    -recent_attachment = attachments.shift
    -recent_attachment.uploader_name
    -recent_attachment.created_at(most recent)
    -Download button
    -attachments.each do
        -attachment.uploader_name
        -attachment.created_at(least recent)
```

Comment: after reading the docs to understand what you did, I realize it will work, however I am getting `undefined method '-@' for Wed, 21 May 2014 19:53:52 UTC +00:00:Time` in line...`@sorted_attachments_by_type = @attachments_by_type.inject({}){|hash, (key, value)| hash[key] = value.sort_by{|a| -a.created_at; hash}}` I had to spell them out for myself to make sure I understood it. I don't understand that error though.